# Filtering Zero Values from Quick table calc ( difference )

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table which has dates on the rows and projects in columns. The content of the table display sum of a field called 'Type A Frame'. This field has a value of '1' or NULL.

When placed in the marks shelf the totals are displayed appropriately. And when i use a quick calc field to show the difference from the previous row ( table down ) it displays correctly.

Except, that the issue i have now is there are a number of '0's where there is no change in values. This displays quite a few zeroes in the whole table that i want to get rid of.

Can anyone please guide me on what i need to do here?

P.S the difference displayed on the table allows for negative and positive numbers . I just need to exclude '0' difference values only.

I tried creating calc fields using If and Case statements to display 0 but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Using Filters**

1. Drag the field to Filters
2. Under the General tab, choose the Custom value list radio button
3. Check the "Exclude" checkbox
4. Uncheck the "Include all values when empty" checkbox
5. Enter 0 into the list, *then click the plus button to the right so it gets added*
6. Click OK to save the filter

[image]

**Option 2: Using a calculated field**

This will replace 0 with NULL.

1. Create a calculated field with the content:

```
    IF NOT [original_field] = 0 THEN
      [original_field]
    END
```

2. Throughout your sheet, replace the original field with this new one.